# What is equivalent to Dictionary<TKey, TValue> with size one (count) 1 in C#?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I want to create Key/Value Pair but with only one Set, not Dictionary with multiple pairs. (I don't want to use Array of size 2.)

What is the best way to do in C#?

Comment: You already have two answers: KeyValuePair and Tuple. Especially for Tuple I'd consider to use a custom type where members have proper name. Note they're similar but if performance are (really, in a measured way) important then you should carefully pick right one (one is a value type, the other a reference type).

Comment: You already mentioned the answer in your question. if you would have typed Key/ValuePair c# in google, suprise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a [`KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var keyValuePair = new KeyValuePair<int, int>(1, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks Yuval that is exactly what I was looking for !!

Comment: @JharPaat You welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

The [Tuple](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) should do what you are after:

> Provides static methods for creating tuple objects.

Alternatively, you could always roll your own custom objects which has 2 fields.

Answer (score 1):

For temporary/internal use you can do with *anonymous* object:

```
  var item = new {
    name = "myName",
    value = 456
  };
```